# How to initialize database before hibernate autogeneration in a Spring JUnit Test?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-test

I'm using `spring-boot-test` for some integration test (weblayer + database). As my domain classes are `@Entity`, hibernate will automatically generate the databases in the testdb, which is `h2` embedded.

Question: how can I run an sql script **before** any initialization of hibernate/jpa takes place in the test?

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public void MyITest {
    @Test
    public void test() {
    }
}
```

I added a `src/test/resources/schema-test.sql`, but that does not seem to get picked up by default. Especially not before the hibernate autogeneration stuf..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to use `src/test/resources/schema.sql`

Answer (score 0):

You can use **@Sql** and set path to the script

```
@Test
@Sql({"/test-schema.sql", "/test-user-data.sql"})
public void userTest {
    // execute code that relies on the test schema and test data
}
```

full informations [SPRING TEST Database](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/testing.html#sql)

Comment: Well I need the schema initialization **before** any hibernate auto-generation takes place. Therefore `@Sql` is too late... it is executed after all initialzation took place.